# What headless CMS's handle hierarchical data?

Tags: content-management-system, strapi, headless-cms

I'm looking into headless CMS's eg. Netlify, Strapi, Sanity. However none of them seem to have functionality to handle managing hierarchical data. Am I missing something? can people let me know how they handle hierarchical data in any of the above mentioned CMS's.

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about a database model. Hierarchical model is achievable in every CMS's you mentioned.

For example you could declare `Employee` and `Computer` objects. Then you just need to add a relation between those two. In Strapi for example you just have to add a `relation` field in `Employee` that says `Employee` have one `Computer`

Comment: Thanks for your response @Baptiste Arnaud. I'm probably not explaining this well... I can see that you can create relationships between object types, however if I wanted to store a collection of 'pages' in a hierarchy or in a specific order, whilst I can create an 'order_by' property or 'parent_id' property to the object type there isn't anything in the UI that is going to let a user easily manage this.